# make taskbar icon visible on window hide

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I am trying to make taskbar icon of my application visible after **minimizing** my window. My window can be displayed by **show()** or **showFullScreen()**, so my code for hiding window is:

```
w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

I also tried

```
w.setWindowFlags(w.windowFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::Tool | etc);
```

but still the same: application is minimized but there is no icon on taskbar.

From [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowFlags-prop) I learned that **setWindowFlags**:

> Note: This function calls setParent() when changing the flags for a window, causing the widget to be hidden. You must call show() to make the widget visible again

But I can't use **show()** 'cause I wanna hide it.

How this can be done? Should I use WinApi or there is a QT-way, that I missed? (**Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint** flag is necessary)

UPD1: I have my own system tray implemented, by I need icon on taskbar

UPD2: I've tried both **showMinimized()** and **setWindowState(Qt::WindowMinimized)**. In first case there is icon on taskbar but after restoring the window (which was showed by **showFullScreen()**) there are window controls: minimize, close. caption etc. In second case it minimizes and restores correctly as I want, but there is no icon on taskbar.

Comment: From [Managing Taskbar Buttons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179.aspx#Managing_Taskbar_But): *"To prevent the window button from being placed on the taskbar, create the unowned window with the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW extended style. As an alternative, you can create a hidden window and make this hidden window the owner of your visible window."* - I don't know why you are using `Qt::Tool`. Besides that, there is a difference between a hidden window and a minimized window. The former will not get a taskbar button.

Comment: I just said that I tried different combinations of flags

Comment: Do you implement `QSystemTrayIcon` ?

Comment: Minimise the app rather than hiding your main window

Comment: Did you try `QWindow::showMinimized()` instead of `setWindowFlags`?

Answer (score 0):

Well I did what I want. But I used **WinApi** for that. Hope this will help to somebody. So, after all

- for **minimizing** I use following things:

  ```
  ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
  ```
- for **restoring** to "prev" state I use:

  ```
     widget->show(); 
     // or
     widget->showFullScreen();
  ```
- Setting **stayOnTop** flag is done by:

  ```
  // SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE are for ignoring 3rd, 4th, 5th, 6th parameters of the SetWindowPos function
  SetWindowPos(hwnd, stayOnTop ? HWND_TOPMOST : HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
  ```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question you asked (*"I am trying to make taskbar icon of my application visible after hiding my window."*).

Comment: So what id does? I wanted to make taskbar icon of my application visible after hiding my window. With help of Qt I couldn't do it. WinApi helped me. Where is the problem?

Comment: You aren't hiding your window. You are minimizing it. I pointed that out in a comment 19 hours ago.

Comment: Damn, I'm so dumb! A lot of excuses!! I really wanted minimize it. Seems I was very tired when asking this question. Once again sorry, I'll fix my question

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't reply to the original question but for anyone coming here from Google: I had the issue, that after using hide() on my window, when I showed it again via show() (or any other way actually) it wouldn't get its own icon again in the taskbar.
I had to set transientParent = null everytime the window is reopened via the loader I used to open the window originally:

```
graphLoader.item.transientParent = null
graphLoader.item.show()
```

This way the window gets its own taskbar icon again and I can also switch between the two windows via Alt+Tab