# How to show a QMainWindow in the taskbar

Tags: c++, qt, qmainwindow

I am making a desktop application using Qt.

the main window opens one of two other windows, but i need to hide the main window when the others are working, when doing so the program is hidden from the taskbar .

and i want to show them with different title.

This is the first window that is shown in the taskbar

[image]

this is the second window (the child window where the icon of the program is disappeared

[image]

Comment: so you just want to minimize the main window when the others are in use?

Comment: Think this is related to: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708947/make-taskbar-icon-visible-on-window-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708947/make-taskbar-icon-visible-on-window-hide)

Comment: @Mariam yes i do

Comment: @M.Sol it is not the same precisely and also didn't answer my question.

Comment: When you call Hide (same as in WinAPI) it will hide your window, you just want an unusual thing, because you want to hide your window and at the same time keep it on your taskbar, and for that, you need to create some kind of custom solution.

Comment: @AhmadMagdy you do not need a custom solution. Minimizing the window achieves exactly that. In that case, this is a possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599334/minimizing-a-qt-application . Instead of hiding the window just minimize it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimizing a Qt application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3599334/minimizing-a-qt-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the "parent" from your *.cpp file of your other two windows.

Before:

```
TechRoom::TechRoom(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::TechRoom)
```

After:

```
TechRoom::TechRoom(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(), //Remove here
    ui(new Ui::TechRoom)
```